# Can I play COD: Ghosts with my Xbox 360 friends if I have an Xbox One?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I have COD Ghosts for xbox one and my brother has it for xbox 360.  I can see him in my friends list from the menu but I can't seem to join his game or invite him to mine.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Cross-platform play is not possible in Call of Duty: Ghosts, or any other game currently available on the Xbox One.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are only allowed to play with those who are on the same system as you.  This is because you are effectively playing a different game across all systems.  In Battlefield 4 for instance, next gen consoles get more players per match while the old gen systems have to have smaller maps.  I'm not certain if the player counts are different across the CoD games on different systems but I know that you can only play with people on the same console as yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft don't allow cross platform with any game except for Final Fantasy XI with Xbox360 so if you get another game you will have to play on PC or PS4 if you want to cross platform.